# Concat multiple columns with string in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, string-concatenation

I have problem with following sql code:error says

> apex -ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

```
SELECT (ime,', ',prez,', ',br_tel) AS POŠTARI
FROM postari
```

It keeps telling me I miss right parenthesis.

I want multiple columns to be selected as ALIAS, because it works on mySql but I do not really know how to do it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For oracle 10g try this one

```
SELECT (ime||  ',' || prez|| ',' || br_tel) "POŠTARI"
FROM postari
```

[**Concatenation Operator**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm)